# Error in an Insert command

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

below is my insert command I am trying to insert IP addresses into a record in the table. The `IP_Address` attribute has `nvarchar` datatype. However the error shows under the number `206` in the IP address

Code:

`INSERT INTO [IP_Loc].[dbo].[IP_Addresses] (IP_Address) VALUES
(98.137.206.119,98.137.206.126)`

`Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near '.206'.`

Any idea what the problem might be ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two issues - an `NVARCHAR` that is not enclosed in `'`, and a `VALUES` that has *two* values, instead of ONE:

```
INSERT INTO [IP_Loc].[dbo].[IP_Addresses] (IP_Address) 
VALUES ('98.137.206.119'),
('98.137.206.126')
```

Comment: What if I have another column which doesn't accept null in the same table? Because it is showing me `Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Check_Status', table 'IP_Loc.dbo.IP_Addresses'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.`

Comment: @HumamShbib - Then you need to add that column to the insert and give it values. Either that or change its definition to have a default.

Answer (score 3):

Try with:

```
INSERT INTO [IP_Loc].[dbo].[IP_Addresses] (IP_Address) VALUES ('98.137.206.119','98.137.206.126')
```

It seems you are missing the quotes ''

If the table only have one column you will need to do it like:

```
 INSERT INTO [IP_Loc].[dbo].[IP_Addresses] (IP_Address) VALUES ('98.137.206.119')
 INSERT INTO [IP_Loc].[dbo].[IP_Addresses] (IP_Address) VALUES ('98.137.206.126')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO [IP_Loc].[dbo].[IP_Addresses] (IP_Address) VALUES ('98.137.206.119');
INSERT INTO [IP_Loc].[dbo].[IP_Addresses] (IP_Address) VALUES ('98.137.206.126');
```